# Port is forwarded and computer is listening, but connection is refused

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, webserver, port

I'm on OS X 10.12, and I'm trying to port forward ports 22 and 8080.
I'm running a python SimpleHTTPServer on 8080, and the default ssh server on port 22.
I can access the ssh and http servers when I use 127.0.01 and my local ip address, but I get a 'connection refused' error when I try to use my public ip address.

http://www.canyouseeme.org/ reports that both ports are listening

Comment: Are you trying to access the public IP address from your local network?

Comment: Yeah, that shouldn't be a problem right? I got it to work once but we changed routers and I had to reconfigure everything.

Comment: Yes, it probably is a problem. This will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning](http://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.